# Target elements inside an element with SASS

Tags: css, sass

I have a label outside a form and labels insode a form. I want to use SASS to style the labels insode the form different. Here the html:

```
<div class="loginField">

 <label>...</label>

  <form>
        <label>...</label>

        <label>...</label>

   </form>
</div>
```

I thought I could do:

```
.loginField 
    {

       label 
       {
       //css rules for label outside form
       }

       &form{

             label{
             //css rules for label insode the form
             }
        }
     }
```

However, this does not produce CSS rules for the inner labels - they get applied the same styles as the label outside the form...

Comment: `&form`? What do you mean by that? A parent selector there is `.loginField`, how do you intend on combining them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to specify the direct child relationship of the top label

**SASS**

```
.loginField 
    {

       > label 
       {
       color:red;
       }

       & form{ /* note the space */

             label{
             color:green
             }
        }
     }
```

**CSS**

```
.loginField > label {
  color: red;
}
.loginField form label {
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean *direct descendant* or simply *child* as there's no indirect *child* or *stepchild* in DOM hierarchy.

Comment: I think that you don't need `&` here.

Comment: Besides, the problem is occurred by `&form` part in the selector, there should be an space between the ampersand `&` and the `form` or simply omit the `&`.